# a href="#" goes to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several anchor links in my system which has `href="#"`. I expect that when the anchor link is clicked, it will simply go back to the top of the page, but when I click one of my anchor links, it opens a new page.

Here is a sample anchor link which is on my site:

```
<li><a href='#' onClick='deletePost()'> Delete </a> </li>
```

This `delete` link is found on profile.php. The URL will read `http://localhost/profile_page/AliceP` before I click the link, which is as expected. But when I click the link, the URL will change to `http://localhost/#` and direct me to a new page. The link should do nothing except perform a PHP query which is done via the `onClick` event.

The same issue persists for my form elements:

```
<form action='#' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='addfriend' value='Add to Favourites'>
</form>";
```

I have never had this issue before.

Comment: and `deletePost()` does what *exactly?* - The use of `#` implies JS that you tagged as, but haven't included that in your question.

Comment: and no php to support the tag. you can add it back in when there's relevance for it.

Comment: Try changing `a href='#'` to `a href`. I had a similar issue in past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this. This way you bind all the `<a>` elements with `href="#..."` to prevent directing when clicked.

In your form, you can just write `<form method="post">` without action.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e){
  
  // Prevents from directing
  e.preventDefault();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="deletePost()">Delete me</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">This still redirects</a>
```

Comment: You do not realize how many problems you have solved of mine! Elements I don't even remember creating are now appearing and working, thank you! However, `<li><a href='#' onClick='deletePost()'> Delete </a> </li>`still takes me to `http://localhost/#`. If I remove the `href` attribute, the  link then becomes unclickable (with the text cursor appearing).

Comment: This works well for me: https://jsfiddle.net/0qmmkrh8/. You could look into stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation() as well.